# AWS Amplify SES sendmail AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-amplify, amazon-ses

I want to to send an email using the AWS Amplify backend using Simple Email Service (SES) but I keep on getting AccessDenied and many other answers here on SO and around the internet says to set the IAM permissions for sendmail and sendrawemail, which I have done.

This is the error message:

```
2020-08-30T02:19:20.544Z    f3980a87-cac0-4f51-9024-d2f92a8a3596    ERROR   { AccessDenied: User `arn:aws:sts::mynumericalusernumber:assumed-role/myamplifyappCreateAuthChallenge-sampledev/myamplifyappCreateAuthChallenge-sampledev' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:mynumericalusernumber:identity/theaddressiamtryingtosendto@gmail.com'
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message:
   'User `arn:aws:sts::mynumericalusernumber:assumed-role/myamplifyappCreateAuthChallenge-sampledev/myamplifyappCreateAuthChallenge-sampledev\' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendEmail\' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:mynumericalusernumber:identity/theaddressiamtryingtosendto@gmail.com\'',
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  time: 2020-08-30T02:19:20.541Z,
  requestId: 'ab8175a1-af65-443f-9114-248e240ce7f8',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 14.074425708542204 } 'AccessDenied: User `arn:aws:sts::mynumericalusernumber:assumed-role/myamplifyappCreateAuthChallenge-sampledev/myamplifyappCreateAuthChallenge-sampledev\' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendEmail\' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:mynumericalusernumber:identity/theaddressiamtryingtosendto@gmail.com\'\n    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)\n    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)\n    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)\n    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)'
2020-08-30T02:19:20.544Z f3980a87-cac0-4f51-9024-d2f92a8a35
```

It is in a create auth challenge for an OTP (One Time Password) that this happens and here is the code

```
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  //Create a random number for otp
  const challengeAnswer = Math.random().toString(10).substr(2, 6);
  const phoneNumber = event.request.userAttributes.phone_number;

  sendEmail('theaddressiamtryingtosendto@gmail.com', challengeAnswer)

  //For Debugging
  console.log(event, context);


  //set return params
  event.response.privateChallengeParameters = {};
  event.response.privateChallengeParameters.answer = challengeAnswer;
  event.response.challengeMetadata = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';

  console.log("My log");
  
  callback(null, event);
};


function sendEmail(emailAddress, secretLoginCode) { 
  console.log(emailAddress, secretLoginCode);

  // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js

// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});

// Create sendEmail params 
var params = {
  Destination: {
   
   ToAddresses: [
      emailAddress
   ]
  }, 
  Message: {
   Body: {
    Html: {
     Charset: "UTF-8", 
     Data: `<html><body><p>This is your OTP login code:</p>
     <h3>${secretLoginCode}</h3></body></html>`
    }, 
    Text: {
     Charset: "UTF-8", 
     Data: `Your OTP login code: ${secretLoginCode}`
    }
   }, 
   Subject: {
    Charset: "UTF-8", 
    Data: "OTP code"
   }
  }, 
  Source: "noreply@my-own-verified-domain.com"
 };

// Create the promise and SES service object
var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'}).sendEmail(params).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
sendPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log(data.MessageId);
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack); // This is where the error shown is from
    console.log(params);
  });

}
```

My IAM permissions for the user

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I still got the same error so I added this

Domain verification for says

- Verification Status Verified
- DKIM Status Verified
- Enabled for Sending Yes

The SES is in sandbox mode and I have verified theaddressiamtryingtosendto@gmail.com and the test email reaches the inbox.

I feel that I have done everything correctly so what am I missing for this to work?

Comment: The IAM permissions you've posted, they are attached to what user/role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marcin lead me to the solution and should have the salute for solving this

I had attached IAM permissions to the IAM user and not to the lambda/role. When this was done it just started working.

I am still unsure if I need the same permissions in both IAM user and the role. A little bit afraid of doing changes to this now but if anyone knows please comment.