# AWS SES breaks an email styles

Tags: node.js, amazon-ses, mjml

I have a bunch of emails which are written using MJML. The output HTML seems to be correct.

As an email sender, I'm using AWS SES. But after sending, all my CSS styles in an email are broken. To send an email, I'm using method `ses.sendEmail`.

I have tried to use CSS injected in HTML head and inline styles. Does not work.

What could be the problem with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, check your HTML. Send it through either of these free sites: https://www.putsmail.com (requires a free Litmus account; they're an established and reputable Email Service Provider, ESP) or https://useparcel.com/ (an editor for email HTML; put your HTML in the editor and use their free send feature). With putsmail, don't accept their offer to inline your CSS for you--that'll change your HTML.

When each email arrives, compare the HTML received to what you sent. Diff tools are helpful.

I just sent a 1300+ line HTML file through each of those. For both, every character arrived unchanged, except for blank lines after the `</html>`. That's okay with me!

Compare the rendering to what you see in one of the MJML rendering tools (maybe https://mjml.io/try-it-live or the MJML desktop app https://mjmlio.github.io/mjml-app/). Do not depend on the rendering in any one email client as fully representative of the HTML; most of them have quirks. (I'm lookin' at you, all Outlooks except Apple's! And GMail. And Yahoo!. More at https://caniemail.com/ .)

I did a little research on AWS `ses.sendmail`. There's important advice and information at both of these.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-sendmail.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html

I found an SO ticket from a little less than a year ago that could be relevant.
[AWS Amplify SES sendmail AccessDenied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653722/aws-amplify-ses-sendmail-accessdenied)

Recommend you review all that. Maybe something there will improve your experience.

Last, some standard advice from the world of email HTML. If you get `sendmail` working, perhaps it doesn't apply.

Send your HTML using an ESP that doesn't change your HTML. For people sending lots of email, there are lots of good reasons for using an ESP. Many provide valuable services. By the same token, some ESPs change the HTML before sending; lots of us avoid them.

I hope you get it figured out. Email HTML is, as you're experiencing, anything but easy.